# Apache Spark ALS - how to perform Live Recommendations / fold-in anonym user

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I am using Apache Spark (Pyspark API for Python) ALS MLLIB to develop a service that performs **live recommendations** for anonym users (users not in the training set) in my site. 
In my usecase I train the model on the User ratings in this way:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
ratings = df.map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))
rank = 10 
numIterations = 10
model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations)
```

Now, each time an **anonym user** selects an item in the catalogue, I want to **fold-in** its vector in the ALS model and get the recommendations (just like the *recommendProducts()* call), but **avoiding the re-training of the whole model**.

Is there any way to easily do the **fold-in** of the new anonym user vector after training the ALS model in Apache Spark?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To make things clear: do you just want to run your model on a test set, or do you want some kind of "model serving" solution to power a web site in real time?

Comment: I definitively want the "model serving" solution to power a web site in real time!

Comment: I'm flagging this question as a duplicate, hopefully it will get more exposure by being linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509335/how-to-update-spark-matrixfactorizationmodel-for-als

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Spark MatrixFactorizationModel for ALS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509335/how-to-update-spark-matrixfactorizationmodel-for-als)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537470/als-model-how-to-generate-full-u-vt-v

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Open Source **"model server"** solutions that I have seen *advertised*, but have no hands-on experience on. I also heard of a commercial offering, but can't just remember the name right now.
So make your own opinion, and keep a watch on possible alternatives.

[PredictionIO](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/start/) *(the start-up has been gobbled by SalesForce but their solution is still available)* uses a Spark+Hadoop+HBase stack, plus some kind of web server component.

[MLeap](http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/spark-summit-eu-talk-by-mikhail-semeniuk-hollin-wilkins) is yet-another-ML-library-with-limited-feature-set, which can be plugged into Spark/Scikit-Learn/whatever, and can spawn a web service -- or export your model to a hosted solution named Combust.ml

[MLDB](https://mldb.ai/) is yet-another-ML-library-with-limited-feature-set, completely outside of the Python/Spark ecosystem, but claims full integration with TensorFlow -- including the ability to [import existing Deep Learning models and tweak them for different uses](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/10/mldb-machine-learning-database.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me these suggesions, I will take a look soon. 
However, as I wrote in the original question, I want to implement my own solution using Apache Spark MLLIB, so I need a technical answer on how to do it on that library.