# ALS model - predicted full_u * v^t * v ratings are very high

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm predicting ratings in between processes that batch train the model.  I'm using the approach outlined here: [ALS model - how to generate full_u * v^t * v?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537470/als-model-how-to-generate-full-u-vt-v)

```py
! rm -rf ml-1m.zip ml-1m
! wget --quiet http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-1m.zip
! unzip ml-1m.zip
! mv ml-1m/ratings.dat .

from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating

ratingsRDD = sc.textFile('ratings.dat') \
               .map(lambda l: l.split("::")) \
               .map(lambda p: Rating(
                                  user = int(p[0]), 
                                  product = int(p[1]),
                                  rating = float(p[2]), 
                                  )).cache()

from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS

rank = 50
numIterations = 20
lambdaParam = 0.1
model = ALS.train(ratingsRDD, rank, numIterations, lambdaParam)
```

Then extract the product features ...

```py
import json
import numpy as np

pf = model.productFeatures()

pf_vals = pf.sortByKey().values().collect()
pf_keys = pf.sortByKey().keys().collect()

Vt = np.matrix(np.asarray(pf_vals))

full_u = np.zeros(len(pf_keys))

def set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, key, val):
    try:
        idx = pf_keys.index(key)
        full_u.itemset(idx, val)
    except:
        pass

set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 260, 9),   # Star Wars (1977)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 1,   8),   # Toy Story (1995)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 16,  7),   # Casino (1995)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 25,  8),   # Leaving Las Vegas (1995)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 32,  9),   # Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 335, 4),   # Flintstones, The (1994)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 379, 3),   # Timecop (1994)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 296, 7),   # Pulp Fiction (1994)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 858, 10),  # Godfather, The (1972)
set_rating(pf_keys, full_u, 50,  8)    # Usual Suspects, The (1995)

recommendations = full_u*Vt*Vt.T

top_ten_ratings = list(np.sort(recommendations)[:,-10:].flat)

print("predicted rating value", top_ten_ratings)

top_ten_recommended_product_ids = np.where(recommendations >= np.sort(recommendations)[:,-10:].min())[1]
top_ten_recommended_product_ids = list(np.array(top_ten_recommended_product_ids))

print("predict rating prod_id", top_ten_recommended_product_ids)
```

However the predicted ratings seem way too high:

```py
('predicted rating value', [313.67320347694897, 315.30874327316576, 317.1563289268388, 317.45475214423948, 318.19788673744563, 319.93044594688428, 323.92448427140653, 324.12553531632761, 325.41052886977582, 327.12199687047649])
('predict rating prod_id', [49, 287, 309, 558, 744, 802, 1839, 2117, 2698, 3111])
```

This appears to be incorrect.  Any tips appreciated.

Comment: I did get good results using this, but this was with implicit feedback, ratings were 0 for negative or unknown, and 1 for positive. I did get prediction between 0 and 1 and I was using rank as a metric, i.e., not paying much attention to the scores.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I haven't looking into implicit feedback yet.  If you post your comment as an answer, you will get the bounty by default if no one else answers ;)

Comment: @yoh.lej Ah, that explains why I was getting such inflated ratings like Chris!  So assumption is that ratings are binary then.  Yohan, could you briefly explain what this formula is based on?  I tried googling for similarity measures and didn't see it.  What are we calculating similarity to?  Intrigued because I'm currently taking linear algebra class.  Just logically, seems like we would want to determine which existing user this new user is most similar too, and use their factors to predict ratings -- is this approach more sophisticated?  Thanks! (Chris - check out ALS.trainImplicit)

Comment: Sure, I'll elaborate a bit more in an answer

Comment: @yoh.lej- How were you using rank as a metric? Can you please share some more details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the approach mentioned would work if you only care about the ranking of the movies. If you want to get an actual rating there seem to be something of in terms dimension/scaling.

The idea here, is to guess the latent representation of your new user. Normally, for a user already in the factorization, user i, you have his latent representation `u_i` (the ith row in `model.userFeatures()`) and you get his rating for a given movie (movie j) using `model.predict` which basically multiply `u_i` by the latent representation of the product `v_j`. you can get all the predicted ratings at once if you multiply with the whole v: `u_i*v`.

For a new user you have to guess what is his latent representation `u_new` from `full_u_new`.
Basically you want 50 coefficients that represent your new user affinity towards each of the latent product factor. 
For simplicity and since it was enough for my implicit feedback use case, I simply used the dot product, basically projecting the new user on the product latent factor: `full_u_new*V^t` gives you 50 coefficient, the coeff i being how much your new user looks like product latent factor i. and it works especially well with implicit feedback.
So, using the dot product will give you that but it won't be scaled and it explains the high scores you are seeing.
To get usable scores you need a more accurately scaled `u_new`, I think you could get that using the cosine similarity, like they did [here]https://github.com/apache/incubator-predictionio/blob/release/0.10.0/examples/scala-parallel-recommendation/custom-query/src/main/scala/ALSAlgorithm.scala

The approach mentioned by @ScottEdwards2000 in the comment is interesting too, but rather different. You could indeed look for the most similar user(s) in your training set. If there are more than one you could get the average. I don't think it would do too badly but it is a really different approach and you need the full rating matrix (to find the most similar user(s)). Getting one close user should definitely solve the scaling problem. If you manage to make both approach work you could compare the results!